# Is is better to have a big web page with a small amount of JS, or to have a small web page with some JS-generated content?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page with a lot of dialogs which differs each other by the title and a little part of the content.

In terms of rendering speed (I don't care of compatibility issues), should I put all the dialogs in the HTML code (Twig template in reality) ?
Or should I put only one dialog and dynamically edit his title and his content, depending on which button user has clicked, by using JavaScript ?

In other terms is it better to have a big web page (in size) or a smaller web page but with JS to generate a part of the content ?

Comment: Reminds me of [the recent Twitter changes](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/05/improving-performance-on-twittercom.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of document readiness at load time, it's typically best to have all dialogs in HTML; you can compress HTML pretty well using `gzip` so don't worry too much about it. You can leverage `Last-Modified` and `ETag` to manage content caching for an additional reduction of network traffic.

Having the dialogs inside the HTML may have some SEO benefits as search engines scrape your site.

On the other side of the spectrum is a bare HTML page (small) whereby all dialog contents are loaded dynamically using JavaScript. I don't find it particularly convenient to dynamically construct forms using JavaScript, so I typically implement a component loader system that loads HTML, CSS and JS in one go; this way I can maintain the HTML using my favorite editor. If you manage the appearance well, the user won't notice the load much.

Perhaps you could go for something in the middle; often-used dialogs are inside the HTML, whereas the lesser used get loaded on-demand. In the end it's all about user experience, how they perceive the speed of your site.